# how to use Diff command ignoring text with in a line and get unmatched data based on condition

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, diff

I am trying to get the below output with the given input.
Can this be done with `diff` command? I am trying this syntax but not working:

```
diff -a  --suppress-common-lines a.txt b.txt
```

Here are the two input files:

First `a.txt`:

```
abc abc/d_4.1/efg 35 
xyz abc/d_4.1/efg 36
mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38
```

And `b.txt`:

```
abc abc/d_4/efg 35
xyz abc/d_4/efg 36
mno abc/d_4/efg 40
```

I'm need this output (below is the `diff` irrespective of `d_4.1` and `d_4` in both the files):

```
mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38
mno abc/d_4/efg  40
```

Comment: `diff` works on lines, so you shouldn't expect it to ignore part of a line in its comparisons. [Please edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/352467/edit) to explain why the `abc` and `xyz` lines are to be ignored in the output but both instances of the `mno` line are to be shown. Is it because their last columns are different?

Comment: Actually, let's rephrase the question. Is it correct to describe your requirement like this -- « _Using the first field as a key, you want to print lines where the third (last) field is different._ »?

Comment: i am considering this as a line   "abc         abc/d_4/efg             35"

Comment: You haven't explained, as asked. You also haven't put your update in your question, as asked. Please make it easy for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utility `diff` has not an option to skip fields.

I tried to make it work with cut & uniq. Thought bellow will work, column 2 will be missing from the output.

```
$ cut -d/ -f1,3 file1 file2 |sort |uniq -u  #column 2 is skipped
```

As a more correct solution i propose the following awk:

```
awk -F" |/" '{a=$1$2$4$5;seen[a]++;out[a]=$0}END{for (i in seen) if (seen[i]==1) print out[i]}' file1 file2
```

I use field separator either space or slash / , since your input data given include some extra spaces in the end of each line.

Even if your real data does not contain extra white space, above solution will still work ok.

The logic of awk is the following: it emulates uniq -u , skipping the middle column (`/d_4/`).
It just prints all the unique lines between both file1 and file2 (concatenated by awk).

Testing ([see also online test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNHZkWll0czJyNWM))

```
cat file1 
cat file2 
echo "awk start:"
awk -F" |/" '{a=$1$2$4$5;seen[a]++;out[a]=$0}END{for (i in seen) if (seen[i]==1) print out[i]}' file1 file2
echo "awk end"

#Output
#file1            
abc abc/d_4.1/efg 35
xyz abc/d_4.1/efg 36 
mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38
#file2
abc abc/d_4/efg 35
xyz abc/d_4/efg 36 
mno abc/d_4/efg 40

awk start:      
mno abc/d_4/efg 40
mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38
awk end
```

Comment: awesome, it is working . many many thank you .

this is working :-
awk -F" |/" '{a=$1$2$4$5;seen[a]++;out[a]=$0}END{for (i in seen) if (seen[i]==1) print out[i]}'

Comment: i am trying to run ./main.sh (the link that you have associate ) but its showing permission denied error.

Comment: @brajkishoredubey I am glad if this helped. There is a button "execute" just above line 1. Press this button.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, and splitting on the `/`, this code will print the two lines when the first field matches and the 3rd field does not.

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "/" }

$1 in a2 && $3 != a2[$1] {
    print $1, a1[$1], a2[$1]
    print
}
{
    a1[$1] = $2
    a2[$1] = $3
}
```

**Results:**

```
$ awk -f test.awk file1 file2
mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38
mno abc/d_4/efg 40
```

Comment: really appreciate your help  but still i am not getting exact output . i am getting below output after executing your script .

abc abc/d_4.1/efg 35 

xyz abc/d_4.1/efg 36

mno abc/d_4.1/efg 38

mno abc/d_4/efg  40

Comment: Look for white space differences.